# HC-05 Bluetooth module connected to Arduino Nano lags every ~5 seconds

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, lag, transmission

have a HC-05 module hooked up to my Arduino Nano (RX-TX and TX-RX, baudrate 9600). The module transmits the data (a string that is read by the RacaChrono app on my phone) at 20 Hz (the frequency can be changed).

But every 5 seconds there is a ~0.3 seconds **lag** in the transmission. The **data and the counter used still get transmitted** but with lag.

Here is all the code I use to gather data from my Kart and transmit that data with the HC-05 module:

```cpp
/*
The code calculates the acceleration and brake pedals position, RPM, current gear, temperature and the laptime
*/

int rpm = 0, gear = 0, brake = 0, acceleration = 0, sensorValue1 = 0, sensorValue2 = 0;
unsigned long count = 0, lastmillis = 0;
volatile int half_revolutions = 0;
unsigned long debounceDelay = 200;    // the debounce time; 
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the gear was changed
unsigned long lastTransmit = 0;     // the last time the $RC2 string was transmitted
int transmitRate = 50;             // transmit the $RC2 string every * milliseconds
int RPMupdate = 100;              // update the RPM counter every * milliseconds
String readString;               // used in changing the settings with serial commands

/* variables of the laptimer */
float second =  1000;             // 1000 milliseconds in a second
float lapTime = 0;               // the variable that will be passed in the $RC string
long lapTimeDebounce = 1000;    // how much time in milliseconds must pass before reading another pass over the line
long lapMillis = 0;            // How long has it been since the last time the sensor was HIGH
long lapMillis2 = 0;          // How long has it been since the last time the sensor was HIGH (for 2+ sectors)
int sectors = 1;             // the number of split-lines
int line = 0;               // the number of times you passed over the line


void setup(){
  attachInterrupt(0, rpm_fan, RISING); // attach an interrupt on pin number 0 - physical pin No.2
  Serial.begin(9600);       // set the serial baudrate to 9600
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);      // acceleration
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);     // brake
  pinMode(A3, INPUT);    // temperature
  pinMode(10, INPUT);   // laptime
  pinMode(11, INPUT);  // gear +
  pinMode(12, INPUT); // gear -

}
void loop(){
  long ddd=millis();
  while (Serial.available()) {      // loop that runs only when serial data is receiver by the Arduino
   delay(10);  
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
     char c = Serial.read();     //gets one byte from serial buffer
     readString += c;           //makes the string readString (1st byte + second byte + third byte + ...)
   } 
 }
 int a=readString[0];         // transforms the first byte received into an integer and stores it in the variable "a"
 int b=readString[1];
 int c=readString[2];

 if (readString.length()>0) {         // if there is something in the receiving serial of the Arduino  
   if (a==49 && b==49){gear=0;}      //change the settings based on the numbers received 
   if (a==49 && b==50){gear=1;}     // the numbers that a and b are compared to are the ASCII values of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
   if (a==50 && b==49){sectors=1;}
   if (a==50 && b==50){sectors=2;}
   if (a==50 && b==51){sectors=3;}
   if (a==50 && b==52){sectors=4;}
   if (a==51 && b==49){RPMupdate=20;}
   if (a==51 && b==50){RPMupdate=50;}
   if (a==51 && b==51){RPMupdate=100;}
   if (a==51 && b==52){RPMupdate=200;}
   if (a==52 && b==49){transmitRate=20;}
   if (a==52 && b==50){transmitRate=50;}
   if (a==52 && b==51){transmitRate=100;}
   if (a==52 && b==52){transmitRate=200;}
   if (a==53 && b==49){debounceDelay=100;}
   if (a==53 && b==50){debounceDelay=150;}
   if (a==53 && b==51){debounceDelay=200;}
   if (a==53 && b==52){debounceDelay=250;}   
   readString="";     // empties the string variable
 }


  if (sectors == 1){
    if ((millis() - lapMillis) > lapTimeDebounce && digitalRead(10) == HIGH){      // if the lap time sensor is triggered and enough time has passed since the last trigger (for debounceing)
      lapTime = time();       // calculate how many seconds have passed
      lapMillis = millis();  //reset the last time the sensor was triggered
    }
  }
  if (sectors > 1){
    if ((millis() - lapMillis2) > lapTimeDebounce && digitalRead(10) == HIGH){// if the lap time sensor is triggered and enough time has passed since the last trigger (for debounceing)
      line = line + 1;              // a split line was crossed
      if (line == (sectors +1)){   // if enough split lines have been crossed
        lapTime = time();         // calculate how many seconds have passed since crossing the start/finish line
        lapMillis = millis();    //reset the last time that the start/finish line was crossed
        line = 0;               // reset the split lines
      }
      lapMillis2 = millis();  // reset the last time that the sensor was triggered
    }
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay && digitalRead(11) == HIGH){   // if the gear+ sensor has been triggered and sufficient time has passed since last trigger
    gear += 1;
    if (gear>6){  // if you are in sixth gear and trigger the gear+ sensor the display remains 6
      gear=6;
    }  
    lastDebounceTime = millis();    
  }
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay && digitalRead(12) == HIGH){
    gear -= 1;
    if (gear<1){  // if you are in first gear and trigger the gear- sensor the display remains 1
     gear=1;
    }
    lastDebounceTime = millis();    // reset the time when the last gear was changed    
  }  

  /* //temperature reading
  int reading = analogRead(2);  // converting that reading to voltage, for 3.3v Arduino use 3.3
  float voltage = reading * 5.0;
  voltage /= 1024.0; 
  float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100 ;  //converting from 10 mv per degree wit 500 mV offset to degrees ((voltage - 500mV) times 100)                                           
  */
  sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
  sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
  acceleration = map(sensorValue1, 0, 1023, 0, 100);  //maps the input value of 0-1023 to 0-100
  brake = map(sensorValue2, 0, 1023, 0, 100);        //maps the input value of 0-1023 to 0-100

  if (millis() - lastmillis >= RPMupdate){    // Update every one hundredth of a second.
    detachInterrupt(0);                      // Disable interrupt when calculating
    rpm = half_revolutions * 60;            // Convert frequency to RPM, note: this works for one interruption per full rotation. For two interrupts per full rotation use half_revolutions * 30.
    half_revolutions = 0;                  // Restart the RPM counter
    lastmillis = millis();                // Update lasmillis
    attachInterrupt(0, rpm_fan, RISING); // enable interrupt
  }
  if (millis() - lastTransmit >= transmitRate) {         // send the $RC2 string every *transmitRate* milliseconds
    String buffer = "RC2,," + String(count) + ",,,," + rpm + "," + gear + "," + acceleration + "," + brake + /*"," + temperatureC + */"," + String(lapTime) + ",,,,,"; // construct the $RC2 string using the variables and accounting for the format RaceChrono asks for
    String checksum = String (checkSum(buffer), HEX);  // calculate the checksum of the RC2 string

    char crc = checkSum (buffer);
    String data = "$" + buffer + "*";
    Serial.print (data);

    if (crc<16){           // if the HEX value of the checksum is one character, add "0" in front
     Serial.print ("0"); 
    }
    Serial.println (checksum);

    if (count == 65535){
      count = 0;                 // reset the counter variable when it reaches 65535 (the max value an int can hold)
    }
    else
      count += 1;             // increment the count variable
    lastTransmit = millis(); // reset the time when the last $RC2 string was transmitted
  }  
}

/* function that calculates the NMEA checksum and returns the value */
char checkSum(String chars) {
  char check = 0;
  for (int c = 0; c < chars.length(); c++) {
    check = char(check ^ chars.charAt(c));
    }
  return check;
}

/* function for the RPM counter */
void rpm_fan(){
 half_revolutions++; 
}

/* function for the timer */
float time(){
  long timeNow = (millis() - lapMillis);    // calculate how many milliseconds took to do a lap
  float seconds = timeNow / second;        // calculate how many seconds (with decimals) is the amount of milliseconds
  return seconds;                         // return the value as a float
}
```

And here is a sample of the output:

```
$RC2,,1,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*28
$RC2,,2,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2b
$RC2,,3,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2a
$RC2,,4,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2d
$RC2,,5,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2c
$RC2,,6,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2f
$RC2,,7,,,,0,0,83,30,0.00,,,,,*2e
```

The first number after `$RC2` is the counter. (Every iteration is transmitted, but every 5 seconds there is some lag)

The lag causes the app to misread some data (because the transmit rate drops from 20 Hz to 19.1-19.4 Hz)

**Can anyone see a problem that would cause this lag?**
Also if you have suggestions to improve the code, I am more than happy to implement them.

Comment: Every byte you receive causes 10 ms of delay.

Comment: Well, it seems that putting the line:  <readString="";> into the <if (readString.length()>0) {}> condition solved the problem. At least I think this did it.